# How to Catch Error "One or more validation errors occurred."?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

After moving from .NET 2 to .NET 6, my web API got a lot of JSON parsing error.

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-19e12bbbc267ceb1d8bd59abd7bd3086-4f3def60f992630d-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.employeeId": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.employeeId | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 23."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to catch them for logging, is it possible?

This is my Configure() pipeline order in Startup.cs

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseCors();
app.UseSession();
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(MyCustomLoggingMiddleware));
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(EndPoint =>
{
   EndPoint.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: About you want to get custom logging, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider).

Comment: Regarding the JSON parsing error, can you share [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With these alone I can't locate the problem, but maybe `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` or `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>{var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters. Add(enumConverter);});` two methods will help you. The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).